# What is the second parameter in Navigation.findNavController(Activity, @IdRes int viewId)

Tags: android, android-navigation

Learning this and reading the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing) I cant grasp what I should put in this `viewId`

```
Navigation.findNavController(Activity, @IdRes int viewId)
```

I did the [Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/#0) for the  Navigation Architecture Component  but that´s Kotlin code. I need java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the id of the [NavHostFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/fragment/NavHostFragment) within the activity.

Comment: Do you mean the `app:startDestination="@+id/home_dest">` in the xml?

Comment: No. I mean the <fragment> element in the activity that contains the attributes         android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment" ,
 android:defaultNavHost="true" and android:navGraph="your_navigation_graph". This is the NavHostFragment for which you are trying to find a navController.